# How to retrieve only those column from a table corresponding to which a particular value is present in other column in another table in sql query

Tags: sql-server

I have **two tables in a database** ,namely **main.vacuum_status and main_vacuum_analog**. **

```
logtime is a common field
```

of both the tables.
In main.vacuum_status there are column namely and st1_vs1_bag1_onoff..in this way there are eight columns upto st1_vs1_bag8_onoff.Some of these columns have 0 or 1 as a value respectively.In another table there are columns st1_vs1_bag1_rb till st1_vs1_bag8_rb with some real type values.

**`Condition`**

Now I want a sql query which check whenever there is 1 in st1_vs1_bag1_onoff.. columns then the real type values of another table column st1_vs1_bag1_rb...should be dispalyed.i.e if st1_vs1_bag8_onoff is 0 then  st1_vs1_bag8_rb should not be displayed and if  st1_vs1_bag8_onoff is 1 then the value of st1_vs1_bag8_rb sholud be displayed.

Is there any such sql query??

**`EDIT 1`**

By looking at the answers ,I formed my sql query as

```
select 
  case when a.st1_vs1_bag1_onoff='0' and a.logtime=c.logtime then c.st1_vs1_bag1_rb ELSE 'Value when 0' END as st1_vs1_bag1_rb ,
  CASE when a.st1_vs1_bag2_onoff='0' and a.logtime=c.logtime then c.st1_vs1_bag2_rb else '0' END as st1_vs1_bag1_rb ,
  CASE when a.st1_vs1_bag3_onoff='0' and a.logtime=c.logtime then c.st1_vs1_bag3_rb else '0' END as st1_vs1_bag1_rb ,
  CASE when a.st1_vs1_bag4_onoff='0' and a.logtime=c.logtime then c.st1_vs1_bag4_rb else '0' END as st1_vs1_bag1_rb ,
  CASE when a.st1_vs1_bag5_onoff='0' and a.logtime=c.logtime then c.st1_vs1_bag5_rb else '0' END as st1_vs1_bag1_rb ,
  CASE when a.st1_vs1_bag6_onoff='0' and a.logtime=c.logtime then c.st1_vs1_bag6_rb else '0' END as st1_vs1_bag1_rb ,
  CASE when a.st1_vs1_bag7_onoff='0' and a.logtime=c.logtime then c.st1_vs1_bag7_rb else '0' END as st1_vs1_bag1_rb ,
  CASE when a.st1_vs1_bag8_onoff='0' and a.logtime=c.logtime then c.st1_vs1_bag8_rb else '0' END as st1_vs1_bag1_rb ,

from main_vacuum_status a INNER JOIN main_vacuum_analog c ON a.LOGTIME = c.LOGTIME
```

But error is being shown **`Incorrect syntax near form`**

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information you provided, you could do something like the following :

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN st1_vs1_bag1_onoff = 1 THEN st1_vs1_bag1_rb END AS st1_vs1_bag1_rb
    CASE WHEN st1_vs1_bag2_onoff = 1 THEN st1_vs1_bag2_rb END AS st1_vs1_bag2_rb
    CASE WHEN st1_vs1_bag3_onoff = 1 THEN st1_vs1_bag3_rb END AS st1_vs1_bag3_rb
    CASE WHEN st1_vs1_bag4_onoff = 1 THEN st1_vs1_bag4_rb END AS st1_vs1_bag4_rb
    CASE WHEN st1_vs1_bag5_onoff = 1 THEN st1_vs1_bag5_rb END AS st1_vs1_bag5_rb
    CASE WHEN st1_vs1_bag6_onoff = 1 THEN st1_vs1_bag6_rb END AS st1_vs1_bag6_rb
    CASE WHEN st1_vs1_bag7_onoff = 1 THEN st1_vs1_bag7_rb END AS st1_vs1_bag7_rb
    CASE WHEN st1_vs1_bag8_onoff = 1 THEN st1_vs1_bag8_rb END AS st1_vs1_bag8_rb
FROM main_vacuum_status S
INNER JOIN main_vacuum_analog A
    ON  S.logtime = A.logtime
```

if *st1_vs1_bag*_onoff* is different than 1, *st1_vs1_bag*_rb* will be *NULL*.
If you want to display a default value instead, put it in the *ELSE* part, like this :

```
CASE WHEN st1_vs1_bag1_onoff = 1 THEN st1_vs1_bag1_rb ELSE 'Value when 0' END AS st1_vs1_bag1_rb
```

Comment: ,its showing st1_vs1_bag1_onoff =1 is invalid column name.i even tried S.st1_vs1_bag1_onoff ,then its shows the message that **the multi-part identifier could not be bound**

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following :

```
SELECT LOGTIME
,
,CASE 
    WHEN st1_vs1_bag1_onoff = 1
        THEN st1_vs1_bag1_rb
    ELSE '<No Value>'
    END AS st1_vs1_bag1_rb
,
   .
   .
   .
   .
   .
   .
,CASE 
    WHEN st1_vs1_bag8_onoff = 1
        THEN st1_vs1_bag8_rb
    ELSE '<No Value>'
    END AS st1_vs1_bag8_rb
FROM main.vacuum_status AL1
INNER JOIN main_vacuum_analog AL2 ON AL1.LOGTIME = AL2.LOGTIME
```

Let me know if this is not what you are looking for.

Comment: ,its showing invalid column name st1_vs1_bag1_onoff

Answer (score 0):

I got what I wanted through this query,both the above answers were helpful:))

```
select c.LOGTIME,
  case when a.st1_vs1_bag1_onoff='0' and a.logtime=c.logtime then c.st1_vs1_bag1_rb ELSE '0' END as st1_vs1_bag1_rb ,
  CASE when a.st1_vs1_bag2_onoff='0' and a.logtime=c.logtime then c.st1_vs1_bag2_rb else '0' END as st1_vs1_bag2_rb ,
  CASE when a.st1_vs1_bag3_onoff='0' and a.logtime=c.logtime then c.st1_vs1_bag3_rb else '0' END as st1_vs1_bag3_rb ,
  CASE when a.st1_vs1_bag4_onoff='0' and a.logtime=c.logtime then c.st1_vs1_bag4_rb else '0' END as st1_vs1_bag4_rb ,
  CASE when a.st1_vs1_bag5_onoff='0' and a.logtime=c.logtime then c.st1_vs1_bag5_rb else '0' END as st1_vs1_bag5_rb ,
  CASE when a.st1_vs1_bag6_onoff='0' and a.logtime=c.logtime then c.st1_vs1_bag6_rb else '0' END as st1_vs1_bag6_rb ,
  CASE when a.st1_vs1_bag7_onoff='0' and a.logtime=c.logtime then c.st1_vs1_bag7_rb else '0' END as st1_vs1_bag7_rb ,
  CASE when a.st1_vs1_bag8_onoff='0' and a.logtime=c.logtime then c.st1_vs1_bag8_rb else '0' END as st1_vs1_bag8_rb 

from main_vacuum_status a INNER JOIN main_vacuum_analog c ON a.LOGTIME = c.LOGTIME and
c.logtime between '2014-10-10 07:17:00' and '2014-10-10 08:46:00'
```

Comment: You don't need the *'and a.logtime=c.logtime'* in your *CASE* statement, it's redundant